# Вывести символ рамки char(179) - char(218) c++

Tags: c++, вывод, символы

Я хочу вывести красивую рамочку

```
  ╔══╗  
  ║  ║  
  ║  ║  
  ╚══╝
```

Такой вывод

```
cout << char(186);
```

работает, но такой

```
cout << "║" << ' ' << '║';
```

нет, а хотелось бы. Вместо этого выводит

```
тХС 14849425
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно хранить и выводить такие символы,
чтоб можно было сделать так

```
string s[3] = {"╔═╗",
               "║ ║",
               "╚═╝"};
    
for (auto t : s)
    cout << t << endl;
```

Я использую Codeblocks.

Answer (score 1):

Работать надо в 866 кодировке, и код писать соответственно...

Вот, убедитесь сами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще раз: и код (текст программы) написан в 866 кодировке, и вывод в консоль в ней же (по умолчанию).

Ну, а если хотите увидеть весь набор псевдографики, то опять же просто выведите в консоль такое:

```
for(unsigned char c = 0xA0; c < 0xF0; ++c)
{
    cout << (char)c ;
}
```

Вот что увидите:

```
абвгдежзийклмноп░▒▓│┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗╝╜╛┐└┴┬├─┼╞╟╚╔╩╦╠═╬╧╨╤╥╙╘╒╓╫╪┘┌█▄▌▐▀рстуфхцчшщъыьэюя
```

Если, конечно, в кодировке 866...

Answer (score -1):

Для того, что бы сделать это, нужно поменять *кодировку* командной строки (по умолчанию, код кодировки в консоли - это `cp866`), так как, то, какие символы выводятся зависит от кодировки. Кодировка символов "рамочки" - это `UTF-8` (`UTF-8` имеет номер 65001). Поэтому надо поменять кодировку на соответствующую.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string s[3] = {"╔═╗",
               "║ ║",
               "╚═╝"};
    
int main(){
    system("@echo off\nchcp 65001"); //Отключаем вывод команд консоли и меняем кодировку
    for (string t : s)
        cout << t << endl;
}
```

Comment: Как раз в 866 кодировке все это есть...

Comment: @Harry, я понял, я еще не очень опытный, но решение работает

Comment: Попробовал такой вариант, но тот же  результат(

Comment: @user552914, когда вы в консоли набираете chcp, что выводит?

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string s[3] = {"╔═╗",
               "║ ║",
               "╚═╝"};
    
int main(){
    system("@echo off\nchcp 65001"); //Отключаем вывод команд консоли и меняем кодировку
    for (string t : s)
        cout << t << endl;
 system("chcp");
} 
такой код даёт
тХФтХРтХЧ
тХС тХС
тХЪтХРтХЭ
Текущая кодовая страница: 866

Answer (score -1):

Насколько я понял, проблема была в том, как Codeblocks кодирует .cpp файлы.
Зайдя в Settings -> Editor -> General settings -> Encoding settings и выставив такие параметры :
[image: параметры]

всё заработало и теперь спокойно выводит и рамки и русский текст.

Comment: И чем это отличается от написанного мною "*Работать надо в 866 кодировке, и код писать соответственно...*"? :)